# MySQL find Count grouped by per month

Tags: mysql, sql

For my problem the general structure of the tables is:

- the Workers are located in different Branches (Branch table).
- Prospective customer register (Registration table) as a Customer (Customer table)
- and can order the products to buy (Order table).

Branch Table:

```
+------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 'branchId' | 'street'     | 'city'          |
+------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 'B002'     | 'Clover Dr'  | 'London'        |
| 'B003'     | 'Main St'    | 'Glagsow'       |
| 'B004'     | 'Manse Rd'   | 'Bristol'       |
| 'B005'     | 'Deer Rd'    | 'London'        |
| 'B007'     | 'Argyll St'  | 'Los Angeles'   |
| 'B008'     | 'Mission St' | 'San Francisco' |
| 'B009'     | 'SOMA'       | 'San Francisco' |
+------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Customer Table:

```
+--------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| 'customerId' |  'fName' |  'lName'  |  'telNo'        |
+--------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| 'CR56'       | 'Aline'  | 'Stewart' | '0141-848-1825' |
| 'CR58'       | 'Jacky'  | 'Ho'      | '0123-1325434'  |
| 'CR62'       | 'Mary'   | 'Tregar'  | '01224-196720'  |
| 'CR74'       | 'Mike'   | 'Ritchie' | '01475-392178'  |
| 'CR76'       | 'John'   | 'Kay'     | '0207-774-5632' |
+--------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Registration Table:

```
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+
| 'customerId' | 'branchId' | 'workerId' | 'joiningDate'         |
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+
| 'CR56'       | 'B003'     | 'SG37'     | '2004-05-02 12:00:00' |
| 'CR58'       | 'B003'     | 'SA9'      | '2004-05-03 12:00:00' |
| 'CR62'       | 'B007'     | 'SA9'      | '2004-05-01 12:00:00' |
| 'CR74'       | 'B004'     | 'SG37'     | '2004-04-04 12:00:00' |
| 'CR76'       | 'B005'     | 'SL41'     | '2004-03-03 12:00:00' |
+--------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+
```

Order Table:

```
+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+
| 'customerId' |  'productId' |  'orderDate'           |
+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+
| 'CR56'       | 'PA14'        | '2004-05-04 11:30:00' |
| 'CR62'       | 'PA14'        | '2004-05-04 14:00:00' |
| 'CR56'       | 'PG36'        | '2004-06-07 11:00:00' |
| 'CR56'       | 'PG4'         | '2004-04-14 12:05:00' |
| 'CR76'       | 'PG4'         | '2004-04-04 10:15:00' |
+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+
```

I am trying to form a query to find the number of orders per Branch within 1, 2, and 3 months of client Registration.

Let's say for example

```
+----------+------------+-----------------+
| 'months' | 'branchId' | 'numberOfOrder' |
+----------+------------+-----------------+
| 1        |  'B003'    |  2              |
| 2        |  'B004'    |  1              |
+----------+------------+-----------------+
```

I tried to group the table by month and date but I am stuck and not able to proceed forward.
Does anyone has any ideas and help me unblock?

I started doing something like this, but I am completely lost at the moment.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT o.orderDate) AS 'count'
FROM
    Order o, Registration r
WHERE
    o.orderDate BETWEEN DATE('2001-01-01') AND DATE('2005-01-31')
GROUP BY YEAR(o.orderDate), MONTH(o.orderDate);
```

But this seems I am pretty far from what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Show us the query you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

Your desired result has nothing in common with your data.

So i assume you want the Order count for every branch.

I added the year also, because it is usually needed and doesn't bother if your data don't go over one year
Update:
Now ot only select orders which was place in the 3 month since the a customer joined
.It is limited by the date_add in the where clause

> ```
> CREATE TABLE registration
>     (`customerId` varchar(4), `branchId` varchar(4), `workerId` varchar(4), `joiningDate` datetime)
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO registration
>     (`customerId`, `branchId`, `workerId`, `joiningDate`)
> VALUES
>     ('CR56', 'B003', 'SG37', '2004-05-02 12:00:00'),
>     ('CR58', 'B003', 'SA9', '2004-05-03 12:00:00'),
>     ('CR62', 'B007', 'SA9', '2004-05-01 12:00:00'),
>     ('CR74', 'B004', 'SG37', '2004-04-04 12:00:00'),
>     ('CR76', 'B005', 'SL41', '2004-03-03 12:00:00')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `order`
>     (`customerId` varchar(4), `productId` varchar(4), `orderDate` datetime)
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO `order`
>     (`customerId`, `productId`, `orderDate`)
> VALUES
>     ('CR56', 'PA14', '2004-05-04 11:30:00'),
>     ('CR62', 'PA14', '2004-05-04 14:00:00'),
>     ('CR56', 'PG36', '2004-06-07 11:00:00'),
>     ('CR56', 'PG4', '2004-04-14 12:05:00'),
>     ('CR76', 'PG4', '2004-04-04 10:15:00')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT  MONTH(o.`orderDate`),r.branchId, COUNT(*) numberOfOrder
> FROM registration r inner join `order` o ON r.`customerId` = o.`customerId`
> WHERE o.`orderDate` BETWEEN r.`joiningDate` AND DATE_ADD(r.`joiningDate`, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
> GROUP BY YEAR(o.`orderDate`),MONTH(o.`orderDate`),r.branchId
> ```
>
> ```
> MONTH(o.`orderDate`) | branchId | numberOfOrder
> -------------------: | :------- | ------------:
>                    4 | B005     |             1
>                    5 | B003     |             1
>                    5 | B007     |             1
>                    6 | B003     |             1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4861004a843a17af98247d7d6ab27cf9)*

Comment: thanks for taking a look. This result is very close to what I am looking for. The only thing which I am not very clear is how to limit this query to be within 1, 2, and 3 months of customer Registration.

Comment: See if this is what you are looking for

Comment: yup it's almost 100% close to what I am looking at. Will try to make any change if needed. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure of what your desired result is, but with this query you can get the count of orders, per branch, within 3 months after registration.

```
SELECT 
    reg.branchId,
    COUNT(reg.branchId) AS 'orderCount'
    FROM `order` AS ord INNER JOIN `registration` AS reg
    ON ord.customerId = reg.customerId
    WHERE reg.joiningDate BETWEEN reg.joiningDate AND DATE_ADD(reg.joiningDate, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
    GROUP BY reg.branchId
```

Result

[image: Result of query]

Is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: this almost closer to what I am looking at expect "within 3 months after registration". My requirements are "within results grouped by 1, 2 and 3 months after registration".

SELECT

Answer (score 0):

You may try below query i guess, having moths calculated on the basis of differences in orderDate and joiningDate -

```
SELECT  abs(ceil(datediff(o.`orderDate`, r.`joiningDate`)/30)) months_join,r.branchId, COUNT(*) numberOfOrder
FROM registration r inner join `order` o ON r.`customerId` = o.`customerId`
GROUP BY YEAR(o.`orderDate`),  abs(ceil(datediff(o.`orderDate`, r.`joiningDate`)/30)),r.branchId
```